# mechanize.Browser fails to submit?

Tags: python, authentication, mechanize

I am using mechanize to login a site with the following form.

```
<form id="loginForm">
         <div class="signinTitle" >
            <span class="regTips" id="logTips"></span>
        </div>
         <ul class="inputBox">
                <li class="loginname">
                    <label>username/email</label>
                    <input id="nameInput" type="text" name="loginname" maxlength="30" value="">
                </li>
                <li class="password">
                    <label>password</label>
                    <input id="pwdInput" type="password" name="password" maxlength="16" value="">

                </li>
                <li id="chechbox">
                    <p class="tip">
                        <input name="remember" type="checkbox" checked="checked"/>
                        <span>remember </span>
                        <span class="forgetPwd"><a href="http://passport.infzm.com/passport/resetPassWord" >forget password</a></span>
                    </p>
                </li>
                <li class="submit clearfix">
                    <input type="submit" id="submitbutton" title="submit" value="login"></input>
                </li>
            </ul>
    </form>
```

and the code I use to login is as follows

```
browser = mechanize.Browser()
browser.open(url)
browser.select_form(nr=1)
browser['loginname']=username
browser['password']=password
browser.submit()
browser.read()
```

But the read() returns the same html as the login page. What's wrong here.

Comment: It is using javascript to submit via ajax via a POST to another endpoint.  Look at http://images.infzm.com/js/com/infzm/passport/passport.js?v=4 and search for `login = function(form)` to see what it is doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The javascript on images.infzm.com/js/com/infzm/passport/passport.js?v=4 shows that the form is submitted via a POST to `/passport/login`.  You will need to do some trickery with mechanize to get it to work.  Basically, you will either need to figure out a way to change the action and method of the form (which I can't remember being possible) or make the post yourself without the use of the form (easier to do as well).  Then, just browse to http://www.infzm.com/ directly since that's what the javascript redirects to when login is successful.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, in this case, will `urllib2` do the job?

Comment: I must say thank you again, you really helps me a lot, saves me lots of time. I got it working by using `requests`.

Comment: Good to hear.  Enjoy :)  And requests really is a great library.